HotReload in VS Code for a simple ASP.NET Core web application
My goal: hit the debug button, the browser will open, I change something in my code, I reload the page and voilà - the page is updated with my changes and I am still in debug mode.
I achieved something that comes near but is not there yet.
I open my terminal an type dotnet watch and then I debugg in VS Code with following configuration
.vscode/launch.json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to .NET Core",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}


Hi @arnie, have your tried to add  "justMyCode": true,  "requireExactSource": false  to configurations in launch.json ?

I solved it by installing .NET Watch from Market Place
